# Spring mvc doesnt find representation for post method

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

have problems with mapping Thymeleaf template to Spring controller.
I run non Spring boot app btw.

So here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div><p><b>Search and modify garage data</b></p></div>
<div>
    <p>Available places are:</p>
    <p th:text="${places}"></p>
</div>
<h3>Select option:</h3>
<br>
<p class="header">add extra places to garage:</p>
<div>
    <form method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="numberOfPlaces" placeholder="add places">
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<p class="header">book chosen place for the specific date:</p>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="setDate">
        <input type="text"  name="id_to_book" placeholder="enter the id of Place you want to book:">
        <input type="text" name="date_to_set" placeholder="enter the date to book(YYYY-MM-DD):">
        <button type="submit" placeholder="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button class="button" onclick="document.location='/'">Go to main menu </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/place_menu")
public class PlaceMenuController {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceController placeController;


    @GetMapping
    public String showPlaces(ModelMap model){
     model.put( "places", this.placeController.getPlaces() ) ;
    return "place_menu";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String add(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer numberOfPlaces , ModelMap model){
        this.placeController.addPlaces( numberOfPlaces  );
        model.put( "places" ,this.placeController.getPlaces())    ;
      return "place_menu";
    }
    @PostMapping ("/setDate")
    public String setDate(@RequestParam(required = false) UUID id_to_book, @RequestParam(required = false) LocalDate date_to_set, ModelMap model) {
        this.placeController.setPlaceForDate( id_to_book,date_to_set);
        model.put( "places" ,this.placeController.getPlaces())    ;
        return  "place_menu";
    }
}
```

Submitting button of the form 'setDate' leads to 404 error:

> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Meantime, first form works as it should, I can add new entities and represent them. I believe I have some mistakes in binding post form with controller's method but have no glue where.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed after added full path to the 'action' in form:

place_menu/setDate.
Though I still don't realise the value of class anotation, cause I still have to manually add it to mapping

Comment: Method level mappings are _appended_ to the class level mapping. So it is normal that your form needs `th:action="@{/place_menu/setDate}"`.